# Difference of two exponentials

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I'm trying to solve this problem and I set it up ok, but trying to do the integral turns into a complete mess. How can I evaluate this nicely?

> $$ X,Y \sim expo(\lambda).  $$ Use a convolution integral to show that
>   the PDF of $L=X-Y$ is $f(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-|t|}$.

The PDF of Y is $f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$.

The pdf of L is
$$
f_L(t) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} F_L(t) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} P(L \leq t) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} P(X - Y \leq t) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} P(X \leq t + Y) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} P(X \leq t + y | Y = y ) f_Y(y) dy \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} P(X \leq t + y  ) f_Y(y)  dy \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} F_X( t + y  ) f_Y(y)  dy \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} F_X( t + y  ) f_Y(y)  dy \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} ( 1 - e^{-\lambda (t + y) } ) f_Y(y)  dy \\
= \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} ( 1 - e^{-\lambda (t + y) } ) (\lambda e^{-\lambda y} )  dy \\
$$

Comment: What makes that integral "a mess"? It looks like a fairly straightforward calculation.

Comment: The problem asks you to use convolution, so you should find the PDF of the sum $X+(-Y)$.

Comment: L has a Laplace distribution; perhaps see the relevant Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

PDF of the sum of 2 independent r.v.'s is equal to convolution of the PDF's, so you need to find PDF of $X+(-Y)$. The PDF of $(-Y)$ is the PDF of $Y$ flipped horizontally.

To find the convolution $f_L(t)$ you should flip horizontally one of the PDF's and shift it to the right (for positive $t$) or to the left (for negative $t$) and integrate the product of the PDF's in the overlap region. Since the negation of $Y$ already flipped its PDF horizontally, the second horizontal flip of $-Y$ means no flip in the end. So we have

- $t\geqslant 0$ : $f_L(t)=\int_t^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-t)}dx$
- $t\leqslant 0$ : $f_L(t)=\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-t)}dx$

If you take the integrals you'll get $f_L(t)=\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|}$